# P-value for the combined effect of the contiuous and binomial parts of a zero-adjusted gamma model

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I have a statistical/R issue that that I have not been able to find a solution for yet, hopefully someone here has some valuable insights into the topic.

My issue is that in my analyses my response variable has a zero-inflated semi-continuous right-skewed distribution that does not include any negative values. When approaching this analysis I found that models (like the ZIP, ZAP, ZINB and ZANB) only accept zero-inflated count data but I found that the book "Beginner's Guide to Zero-Inflated Models with R, by Alain F Zuur and Elena N Ieno" (https://highstat.com/index.php/beginner-s-guide-to-zero-inflated-models) recommends the use of zero-adjusted gamma models (which they call ZAG). These are hurdle models for continuous data and consists of a binary part (bernoulli distribution) and a continuous part (gamma distribution). The output of a ZAG model include the P-values, estimates and std.error for the separate parts and can be used to calculate the mean and variance of the combined parts (i.e. estimated effect from the binary and continuous parts together). What I would like to have however, is the P- values, estimates and std. error from the two parts of the model together and I have not been able to find a obtain this.

Below is the example used in book mentioned above with some additional comments and additions to clarify my issue

```
#simulate binomial data
set.seed(123)
gamma1 <- -1
N <- 1000
Pi <- exp(gamma1) / (1+exp(gamma1))
W <- rbinom(N, size = 1, prob=Pi)

#simulate continuous data
beta1 <- 1 
beta2 <- 2 
X1 <- sort(runif(N))
mu <- exp(beta1 + beta2 * X1)
Yg <- rgamma(n =N, shape = mu, scale = 1 )
Y <- W * Yg
#make data frame
datahurdle <- data.frame (Y = Y, #ZAG data
                          X1 = X1, #Covariate,
                          Yg = Yg, #Gamma data
                          mu = mu, #Mean gamma
                          W = W)  #Bernoulli

#apply two glms, first for the continuous data
datahurdle.pos <- subset(datahurdle, Y >0)
h1 <- glm (Y ~X1, family = Gamma(link = "log"),
           data=datahurdle.pos)
#and then for the binomial data
datahurdle$Y0.1 <- as.numeric(datahurdle$Y >0)
h2 <- glm(Y0.1 ~1, family=binomial, datahurdle)


#use the estimated parameters to calculate mean and variabe of the ZAG model
#calculate mean and variance
beta <- coef(h1)
gamma <- coef(h2)
r <- 1/summary(h1)$dispersion

#mean values of gamma glm 
xg <- model.matrix(h1)  
mu.gamma <- exp(xg %*% beta) #first variable in xg is intercept the second is the covariate X1

#combine for plotting
mu <- rep(1,N)
mu [W == 1] <- mu.gamma

#mean values of the binomial glm
pi <- exp(gamma)/(1 + exp(gamma))
pi <- as.numeric(pi) 

#mean and variance of the ZAG model (combined binomial and continuous parts of the hurdle model)
expy <- pi * mu    
vary <- (1/r)*(pi * r +pi - pi^2*r) *mu^2


plot(mu, ylim=c(1,20))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(expy, ylim=c(1,20))
#fitted values of the combined model are the middle line

summary(h1) #estimate, std. error, t value and p value of continuous part
summary(h2 #estimate, std. error, z value and p value of binomial part
```

I hope my questions is clearly enough formulated and I would be very grateful for any input on this issue and I look forward to reading your replies.

Comment: Try not to be concerned with p-values.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I agree that the reliance on p-values in science is exaggerated but I think being able to show some kind of statistical significance for the combined effect of this model would be helpful for interpreting the results. When fitting a model for zero-inflated count data (e.g. model1<-zeroinfl(count ~ X+some_covariate) in the pscl package and estimating the contrasts using emmeans (output <- emmeans(model1, specs = pairwise ~X) the post-hoc test provides the estimated means and test statistics of the combined output. Do you have any suggestion for how that could be done?

Comment: The peoblem is that a p-value tells you the probabiity of observing your data, or data more extreme, if and only if the null hypothesis is true. This is not helpful for interpreting the results.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).